# Authentication failure in Heroku CLI after password change

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

After a password change on heroku's website, I can't access the heroku api.

When I do `heroku login`, I get *Authentication successful*, even though it shouldn't because the password has changed. It doesn't even ask for my email or password, like it should!

If I try `heroku apps` (or any other *application* related command), I get *Authentication failure*.

If I try `heroku status`, it works.

I don't have any plugins installed.

Logs:

```
$ heroku version
heroku-gem/3.6.0 (i686-linux) ruby/2.1.0
$ heroku logout
Local credentials cleared.
$ heroku login
Authentication successful.
$ heroku apps
Authentication failure
$ heroku plugins
You have no installed plugins.
```

I'll appreciate any help or ideas I can get. I already opened a ticket and waiting for the Heroku Support to get back to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently, changing the password for heroku regenerates a new API key, and I had the wrong **HEROKU_API_KEY** configured. (It regenerates a new one after password change).

I'm posting here the response from the great Heroku's support team, which gave me these suggestions:

- Is there a `~/.netrc` file on your computer? If there is, can you please check if the file contains something Heroku related things? Please remove if there is, and try login again.
- Is there an `HEROKU_API_KEY` environment variable defined on your machine? If yes, could you remove it and login try again?
- Is there a `~/.heroku/credentials` file (with or without an extension) on your machine? If yes, could you remove it and try login again?
- Finally, if none of those work, could try the following command: `GEM_HOME='' BUNDLE_GEMFILE='' GEM_PATH='' RUBYOPT='' heroku login` and see how it goes?

Comment: ++!  After reading a lot of stuff about `heroku accounts` *(which doesn't exist anymore, and the replacement asks for credentials creating a catch-22)* and trying other things that did not help, the GEM commandline did the trick.

Comment: Why in the hell it creates those is beyond me.

Comment: Why in the hell it needs those is beyond me.
Logging in first time? Files obviously either don't exist or aren't configured to an account. Logging in is no problem.
Change password after that? Now the server disagrees with your authentication files, so entering the old or new password doesn't work. AND my account isn't any more secure as a result. The files don't even save me time, because I still need to enter my password anyway.

Answer (score 17):

> After a password change on heroku's website, I can't access the heroku api.

Are you using the `heroku-accounts` plugin?  If so, try uninstalling it.

```
heroku plugins:uninstall heroku-accounts
rm -r ~/.heroku/accounts
heroku logout
heroku login
```

- https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts/issues/56

Comment: You may not have to... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957664/authentication-failure-in-heroku-cli-after-password-change/23414614#23414614

Answer (score 6):

> *Are you using the heroku-accounts plugin? If so, try uninstalling it.*

**You may not need to uninstall it...**

Make sure you are not in a project directory (or you may run into the "account not found" loop).

```
cd
```

List your accounts.

```
heroku accounts
```

On each account where the password was changed

```
heroku accounts:remove ACCOUNT
heroku accounts:add ACCOUNT
```

(I did not need to do anything with the `~/.ssh/config`.)

Reset your default account, if needed.

```
heroku accounts:default ACCOUNT
```

If you changed the account name or `git config --unset heroku.account`.

```
cd /path/to/your/project
git config --add heroku.account ACCOUNT
```

I didn't want to give up on the heroku-accounts plugin.  :)

Answer (score 3):

`heroku accounts:remove personal` or whatever account name you have

`git config --unset heroku.account`

`heroku accounts:add personal` then login

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had multiple heroku accounts managed by [heroku-accounts](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) gem and authentication started failing after I changed one of my account's password.

Steps I followed to make things normal again:

1. Removed the account (that's failing to authenticate) from heroku accounts:

   **heroku accounts:remove account_name**
2. Opened up a **new terminal** and then added the account again that I just deleted:

   **heroku accounts:add account_name --auto**

Here you have to use your **new credentials**.

That's it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `~/.netrc` (this is where the Heroku CLI tool saves the auth tokens) and starting over.

Comment: Nope, haven't got a `~/.netrc` file.

Comment: That's odd. `heroku login` is successful with the right user/pass?

Comment: it didn't even ask for email/pass, just wrote `Authentication successful`. The problem was already solved, I had an environment variable **HEROKU_API_KEY** defined, and after I changed the password, Heroku automatically regenerates it.