# Get "Authentication Failed" in heroku on first login

Tags: ruby, git, bash, heroku, cmd

I cannot log in to heroku in my terminal. I just got heroku for an online web development course and this is the first time I am attempting to log in and it always gives me "Authentication failed." I have tried to log in using two different accounts, I have changed the passwords on the accounts, removed and recreated an account, and uninstalled and reinstalled heroku, and tried with Git Bash as well as command line. None of this has worked. At this point I really don't know what to do and hope that you can help.

Comment: I can login to heroku no issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and apparently, this is an error caused by heroku toolbelt. Heroku engineers are currently investigating this matter at the moment. Let's hope that it'll be fix soon. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but in case others end up on here like me, I had a similar issue and I found the answer in this post: [Authentication failure in Heroku CLI after password change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957664/authentication-failure-in-heroku-cli-after-password-change)

In particular typing this in my Command Line (Terminal in Mac OSX) worked and I could login no problem:

GEM_HOME='' BUNDLE_GEMFILE='' GEM_PATH='' RUBYOPT='' heroku login [source: this was taken from the link above.]

I have no idea why the "GEM" thing worked. Other methods I tried are documented in the link above.

Best.