# heroku run rake db:migrate - Authentication error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, authentication, heroku

Like in title - when I'm trying to run database on Heroku, I receive this error.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3332
 !    Authentication error
```

That's all. I'm following this (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#use-a-database) tutorial, till this moment everything went well. I can't even find any similar topic.

@EDIT
I tried to follow this topic: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts/issues/47 
Even recreating account didn't help.

Comment: There are some pretty good suggestions here for authentication problems on Heroku: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957664/authentication-failure-in-heroku-cli-after-password-change

Answer (score 0):

run the following command

```
heroku run rake db:migrate -app APPNAME
```

if the problem persists
then probably **you are not authorized** 
use this then

```
heroku login
```

enter email and password as registered on heroku then retry.